# How to create a centralized user database over multiple apps

Tags: android, database

What is the best way to have a central or unified user database across multiple apps? Right now i have an app that performs an ECG and another that performs an EEG. each app needs a user before beginning. at the moment each user is separate but i want them to be the same across both apps.

Would i just choose one to host a database and then use a content provider to share the info between the two?

Im not sure if this is relevant but the user base will extend to a couple more apps besides the ones i mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I think [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) is the best choice for you.